# Custom Regex Validator in Parsley.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, parsley.js

**Issue**

I am having a problem creating a custom validator for the Parsley.js plugin. What I'm trying to do is test a value vs a regex. Specifically, I'm trying to validate that a password value includes at least one uppercase and one lowercase letter. The validation code throws an error, but does not return true when the condition has been satisfied.

**HTML**

```
<form name="Form" id="signupform" method="post" action="#" data-parsley-validate data-parsley-excluded="input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset], input[type=hidden], [disabled], :hidden">
      <label for="password1">New Password <span class="req">*</span></label>
      <input name="password" id="password1" type="password" class="password" data-parsley-minlength="1" data-parsley-errors-container=".errorspannewpassinput" data-parsley-required-message="Please enter your new password." data-parsley-mixedcase="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$" data-parsley-required/>
      <span class="errorspannewpassinput"></span>
      <label for="confirm_password1">Confirm Password <span class="req">*   </span></label>
      <input name="Password_2" id="password2" type="password" class="password" data-parsley-minlength="1" data-parsley-errors-container=".errorspanconfirmnewpassinput" data-parsley-required-message="Please re-enter your new password." data-parsley-equalto="#password1" data-parsley-mixedcase="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$" data-parsley-required />
      <span class="errorspanconfirmnewpassinput"></span>
      <input type="submit" name="submitinfo" id="submitsignup" data-theme="b" style="width:100%;" alt="Sign Up Now" value="Submit Account Request" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
  $(function() {
    // Set variables
    var pmixedCase = 'Y';
    var mixedCase = $('.mixedcase');
    var passwordField = $('#password1, #password2');
    var passwordFieldErrors = $('.errorspannewpassinput, .errorspanconfirmnewpassinput');
    // Assemble list of visible password requirements
    // Mixed Case
    if (pmixedCase === 'Y') {
        mixedCase.show();
    } else {
        mixedCase.hide();
    }
    // Custom Validators
    window.Parsley.addValidator('mixedcase', {
        requirementType: 'regexp',
        validateString: function(value, requirement) {
            return requirement.test(value);
        },
        messages: {
            en: 'Your password must contain at least (1) lowercase and (1) uppercase letter.'
        }
    });
});
```

I've included a JSFiddle below.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltv4L5s2/7/)

Comment: Well, the pattern is `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$` but it does not fix the whole problem :(.

Comment: I've updated this in the code sample and Fiddle above. Thanks. I'm quite sure that the issue is present in the addvalidator method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue you're facing is that your JsFiddle is using Parsley 2.1.2 whereas the documentation is already updated to Parsley 2.2.0.

If you look at the Javascript console you'll see an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: window.Parsley.addValidator is not a function

Which means that the version you're using is not yet updated (the previous versions used `window.ParsleyValidator.addValidator`). So, if you simply update Parsley.js to the correct version your code will work. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/Ltv4L5s2/9/).

---

However, there's a simpler way to accomplish what you need (that is, without a custom validator). You can use the built-in Pattern ([`data-parsley-pattern`](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-validators-list)). For example:

```
<form name="Form" id="signupform" method="post" data-parsley-validate data-parsley-excluded="input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset], input[type=hidden], [disabled], :hidden">
    <label for="password1">New Password <span class="req">*</span></label>
    <input name="password" id="password1" type="password" class="password" data-parsley-minlength="1" data-parsley-errors-container=".errorspannewpassinput" data-parsley-required-message="Please enter your new password." data-parsley-pattern="(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*" data-parsley-pattern-message="Your password must contain at least (1) lowercase and (1) uppercase letter." data-parsley-required />
    <span class="errorspannewpassinput"></span>
    <label for="confirm_password1">Confirm Password <span class="req">*</span></label>
    <input name="Password_2" id="password2" type="password" class="password" data-parsley-minlength="1" data-parsley-errors-container=".errorspanconfirmnewpassinput" data-parsley-required-message="Please re-enter your new password." data-parsley-equalto="#password1" data-parsley-pattern="(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*" data-parsley-required data-parsley-pattern-message="Your password must contain at least (1) lowercase and (1) uppercase letter."/>
    <span class="errorspanconfirmnewpassinput"></span>
    <input type="submit" name="submitinfo" id="submitsignup" data-theme="b" style="width:100%;" alt="Sign Up Now" value="Submit Account Request" />
</form>
```

What I've changed:

1. Replaced `data-parsley-mixedcase="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$"` for `data-parsley-pattern="(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*"` on both inputs.

   As per [Marc-André Lafortune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8279/marc-andr%c3%a9-lafortune)'s comment I removed the `^` at the start and the `$` at the end, because the patterns are now anchored.
2. Added `data-parsley-pattern-message="Your password must contain at least (1) lowercase and (1) uppercase letter."` on both inputs.

JsFiddle [available here](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/qL45hxd0/2/).

Comment: Awesome answer!
Note that patterns are now anchored, so `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*` is better, or `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/` to be explicit.

Comment: Thank you, milz. I have accepted your answer because you proposed a working solution.

In my application, I did include the latest release candidate. I just failed to select the correct version my Fiddle. When I updated the version to 2.2.0 in the Fiddle, it did indeed work correctly.

I am aware of the data-parsley-pattern data attribute. The reason I went the custom validator route is because the app will require up to 3 separate regex tests for this field (sorry, failed to mention that).

I appreciate the time and effort you put into your response.

Comment: Thanks @Marc-AndréLafortune. I've updated the answer based on your input. And thanks for the work you've done with Parsley to make it more robust!

Comment: Agreed. It's a dream to work with vs other jQuery validation plugins.

Comment: HTML5 `pattern` is preferred to `data-parsley-pattern`, so it will still work even if JS is disabled.